# parsing JSON with Json.Net to get the Key

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Searched my question and didnt find the answer, I have a JSON file like below:

```
{  
   "handle":"ABCD",
   "Tracks":{  
      "Design":{  
         "rating":402
      },
      "Development":{  
         "rating":1584,
         "reliability":"n/a"
      },
      "Specification":{  
         "rating":923,
         "reliability":"0.13"
      },
      "Conceptualization":{  
         "rating":895
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting a dynamic object of json:

```
dynamic dynObj;
dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
```

how can I get the name of "Tracks" item? I dont know how many tag like "Design" is there nor I know the name of them...

Comment: Where is your Server-Side Model?  Where is that model that represents that JSON Object?

Comment: I am getting it from an API

Comment: Well, that would be how you access it.  From that model, `example.Tracks` for example.

Comment: I can get all of the track items like dynObj["Tracks"], but I want to know how many items are there and the name of them to do sth else.

Comment: Without seeing your model, we don't know how the data is stored.  Ie: `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, and etc.

Comment: its dynamic, i dont know either!

Comment: @MT467 Is there a reason that you need to use a dynamic type?  Does the JSON data returned change frequently?

Comment: Yeah, I need to use dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your (dynamic) scenario, don't use `dynamic`, it does not make sense, since you are looking for schema information about the document, which becomes unavailable through the dynamic model.

So, get a `JObject` by calling `JObject.Parse` on your JSON data.

Then, get the keys as such (taken from the [`JObject.Properties` documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm)):

```
foreach (var prop in myJObject.Properties()) 
{ 
    //returns 'handle' and 'Tracks' for your root object
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value); 
}
```

Or using the enumerator of the `JObject`:

```
foreach (var kvp in myJOBject) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: ^this, or any of the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` overloads that take a type parameter.

Comment: I know handle and tracks are there, how about items under tracks?

Comment: @MT467 Repeat  the same logic for the `Value` of the property.

Comment: @moarboilerplate We don't want a strongly typed value, as the type of the returned object is unknown, as I understand.